# prompt user to enter the size of box and also the character to be used to draw the box then proceed to draw box using these two values

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and am in need of help.

> Prompt user to enter the size of box and
>
> also the character to be used to draw the box then proceed to draw
>   box using these two values.
>
> For ex:
>
> ```
> Enter size of box : 3
> Enter character to use : %
> %%%
> %%%
> %%%
> ```
>
> Your task in this question is to implement the same result but now
>   the drawing of the box will be done in a function called print_box()
>
> You will prompt for user to enter the character to use and size of box
>   as shown
>
> And then call the function print_box() passing the two values obtained
>   in line
>
> ex:
>
> ```
> char_to_use = input('Enter a character: ')
> size = int(input('Size of the box?: '))
> print_box (char_to_use, size)
> ```
>
> Sample run :
>
> ```
> Enter a character: ^
> Size of the box?:4
> ^^^^
> ^^^^
> ^^^^
> ^^^^
> ```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; take the [tour] and see the [help] for more information.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have no clue how to solve this and implement the function. Do you have any idea how I can get started?

Answer (score 0):

Function needs to print `size` rows of `size` characters, so you can use `for` loop and repeating a string with `*` operator. Like this:

```py
def print_box(c, s):
    for r in range(s):
        print(c * s)

char_to_use = input('Enter a character: ')
size = int(input('Size of the box?: '))
print_box(char_to_use, size)
```